# Match part of string not proceeded by a space

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match a substring **only if** it is not proceeded by a space?

In the string below, I want to match only the first and third lines and not the second. In this case the line also needs to start with a `#`

```
#match
 #not match
#match
```

https://regex101.com/r/VE3Q8z/1

The negative lookahead `(?! )` doesn't seem to affect anything. Maybe what I'm looking for is a negative look-behind, but I haven't found any examples (that make sense to me) on how do do so in Javascript.

Comment: Maybe you need [`^#(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/zE53Cs/1)?

Comment: You will need some anchors: https://regex101.com/r/VE3Q8z/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated question. I also need to be able to match following lines that start with #, not just the first.

Comment: So, my suggestion is what you need. See https://regex101.com/r/zE53Cs/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to verify that the string starts with a "#". And then add the "global" and "multiline" flags to it

`/^#+(.*)/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/koOXUB/1

Comment: @spencer.sm I was actually in 1 min before that one ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve it with anchors:

```
^(?! )(#+)(.*)
```

See the afore-mentionned link to your own demo: https://regex101.com/r/VE3Q8z/2

Comment: This actually makes no sense, a `#` is not a space and `(?! )` will always return *true*. The `^(?! )(#+)(.*)` pattern is equal to `^(#+)(.*)` - > so, use what I suggested - `/^#(.*)/gm`

Comment: Awesome! Do you know why it doesn't work without the anchor?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. I always thought the `^` only meant the beginning of the string but it looks like it means beginning of the line.

Comment: @spencer.sm: It means beginning of the line if you turn on the multiline modifier (`m` in the regex101.com emulator)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that makes sense about your simplification `^#(.*)`. I'll probably use that in my project. Thanks for both of your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is your regex :

```
^#(.*)
```

this part ^# match with all string that begin by #. You can modify the last part to match only character or number..